# Loop until the status is either success or failure from output of a command using shell script

Tags: linux, loops, shell, if-statement, sh

I am trying to get the status of an api call and check if it is Success or Failure based on this result api call continues. If it is Success or Failure then exit if condition and loop else continue to call the api to check status.

script :

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    status_check=sudo docker exec $ContainerID calm describe app "test_status" | grep "\"action_create" | cut -c29- | cut -d ")" -f1
    echo "${status_check}"
    if [ "${status_check}" == "SUCCESS" ] || [ "${status_check}" == "FAILURE" ]
    then
        echo "Break"
        break
    else
        sleep 60s
        $status_check
     fi
done
```

For the above script output is : The output is already trimmed to get the specifically but still when its executed below 3 lines are streamed out. I need just the 3rd line to check the condition. It can be RUNNING or POLICY_EXEC or FAILURE or SUCCESS. It has to exit the if condition and loop only for SUCCESS or FAILURE.

```
[2022-12-29 19:26:34] [INFO] [calm.dsl.cli.apps:148] test_status found
[2022-12-29 19:26:34] [INFO] [calm.dsl.cli.apps:157] Fetching app details
SUCCESS
```

Comment: You need `$(...)` around the command in the `status_check=` line.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a lot! Its working as expected.

Comment: However I am getting "tests.sh: line 11: POLICY_EXEC: command not found". As I already mentioned the status can be RUNNING or POLICY_EXEC or FAILURE or SUCCESS. I tried using eval "$status_check" after sleep. But still not working.

Comment: Sounds like you may have put a space after `status=`. There should be no space between `status=` and `$(sudo docker exec ...)`

Comment: There is no space  status_check=$(sudo docker exec ...)

Comment: The problem is this line: `$status_check` That's trying to execute the status as a command. I think you want `echo "$status_check"`

Comment: But I'm not sure why you need that at all, since you already echo it before the `if` statement. You could do something like `echo "Waiting"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I need this task to be completed and send a status to the following tasks. Other scripts which are dependent on this task for completion.

Comment: The following task can use the variable `$status_check` after the loop is done.

Comment: Yes that can be done. I will modify accordingly thanks :)